# insert into mysql table with key value column

Tags: mysql

*I have a table like this:*

**id | user_id | key | value**

1 | 1001 | name | Mike

2 | 1001 | last | Muller

3 | 1001 | phone | 111111

4 | 1002 | name | John

2 | 1001 | last | Smith

3 | 1001 | phone | 999999

---

*How can I INSERT INTO data from a table like this:*

**user_id | name | last | phone**

1001 | Mike | Muller | 111111

Comment: You are going to have fun getting stuff out of your first table.

Comment: @P.Salmon Believe it or not, such a design is fairly common out there, e.g. Wordpress uses this type of key value store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (user_id, `key`, `value`)
SELECT user_id, 'name', name   FROM otherTable UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, 'last', last   FROM otherTable UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, 'phone', phone FROM otherTable;
```

Comment: Its not really clear from the question if this is a first time insert or an insert..on duplicate key.OP does say ;I have a table like this:' which may mean that's how it's defined or it may mean here's what I have, and there's no mention of where updates would come from (maybe always second table) Also (and this is probably a typo) 1001 has multiple same id's with different last names and phones.

Comment: @Dirkiboy My syntax seems to be working fine, [see this demo](https://rextester.com/FXFBV46114), and what you suggested should not be working at all.  Maybe you have some other problem which we can't see right now.

Comment: My answer meets the specifications which your question actually has.  If there is a deficiency, then edit your question and explain more.

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm migrating data from databases. I didn't create these tables, I inherited them from my predecessor. The multiple id's are not a type.